# Standalone app from url run in Chrome conflicts with Chrome itself

Tags: macos, applications, plist, web-browser

The standalone app from http://music.google.com made by [this script](https://www.lessannoyingcrm.com/blog/2010/08/149/Create+application+shortcuts+in+Google+Chrome+on+a+Mac) conflicts with the Chrome browser:

- although the app uses a name „Music“ from info.plist in a dock, it continues to identify itself as Google Chrome in Activity Monitor and when opened in a Full Screen
- so the two instances of the Google Chrome runs with the same name and id, and the Chrome Dock icon focuses the app instead of launching the Chrome.

The same app is identified as Music in dock while as Google Chrome in Full Screen and Activity Monitor:

[image: The same app is identified as Music in dock while as Google Chrome in Full Screen and Activity Monitor]

How to force this app to change the name completely not to interfere with Chrome?

**Details:**

- all the names in info.plist are set to „Music“: CFBundleDisplayName, CFBundleExecutable, CFBundleName
- The app and the script MacOS/Music are both also named as Music.

Comment: I don't use it, but the fluid app might solve this problem neatly for you. http://fluidapp.com

Comment: The Fluig uses just the Safari, where unfortunately the Google Music does not work without Flash (with all its security holes, which I don't need otherwise). I also tried a Radiant Player app, which also requires Flash and has severe performance issues, which makes it unusable.